# multiple String Replaces in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I know this is the wrong way to do it (because it errors) but you can see what i'm trying to do:

```
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@""];
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@""];
```

I have a search term called "terms" and want to output a cleaned up version into "urlTerm"??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` returns a *new string*. The original string `terms` won't be affected by this function. <del>Even if `terms` will be affected, the 2nd statement will never succeed because all spaces has become `+` already in the 1st statement, and no double spaces are left.</del> (OK it turns out that "double space" is a tab. :| )

You could use

```
NSString* urlTerm = terms;
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@""];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@""];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Comment: Your answer made complete sense. But when i build it in Xcode it says "Redefinition of urlTerm" as its error and build fails??

Comment: Was too hasty to put your code in. It now works perfectly now you took away the NSString from each line thanks

Comment: @ben: Please check update. It seems that your double space is actually a tab, which Markdown has untabified it. In practice, You should use `\t` to avoid accidental untabification, and it also makes it clear that there's a tab, not multiple spaces in the first glance.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\t&'-_"]];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *urlTerm = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
urlTerm = [urlTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];
```

etc.